# Delimiter of numpy.savetxt

Tags: python, python-3.x, file-io, numpy

I am trying to write a numpy array to a `.txt` file using [`numpy.savetxt`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.savetxt.html).  To the best I can tell, the following code follows the documentation:

```
z = np.array([1,2,3])
np.savetxt('testdata.txt',z,delimiter='hi')
```

However, the output file, opened with Notepad, shows

```
1.000000000000000000e+002.000000000000000000e+003.000000000000000000e+00
```

without the delimiter `hi` between the values.  Any ideas why this might be?  My goal is to add new lines between each value.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need 2D array, axis 0 is the row, and axis 1 is the column. So I use `z[None, :]` to convert it to 2D array:

```
from StringIO import StringIO
s = StringIO()
z = np.array([1,2,3])
np.savetxt(s,z[None, :],delimiter='hi')
s.getvalue()
```

output:

```
1.000000000000000000e+00hi2.000000000000000000e+00hi3.000000000000000000e+00\n
```

Comment: Thanks HYRY.  Any idea how to separate the entries by a new line?